# Insert data to SWFfile

Tags: asp.net, flash

I am a newer to swf file and asp.net. I want to know that the data from sql database value can be shown in swf file?If data can be shown in swf file, how can i do it? Please advice me a way to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial with some code snippets which demonstrates the principle:

http://keylimetie.com/blog/2007/12/18/how-to-communicate-between-aspnet-and-flash/